# Краткое прилагательное или краткое причастие

Tags: части-речи, краткое-прилагательное, краткое-причастие

> Яблоко соку свежего полно.

Краткое прилагательное, пример из учебника.

> Блюдо соку свежего полно.

Здесь тоже прилагательное или уже причастие? Тогда от какого оно глагола произошло? Ведь не существует глагола 'полнить'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Здесь тоже прилагательное или уже причастие?

Тоже краткое прилагательное. Что блюдо, что сок, — разницы нет.

Данное слово не может быть причастием, но может — наречием.

Наречие — при глаголах. Примеры со словаря Кузнецова:
*Налить полнее ведро.

Полно отразить в своём романе судьбу страны.*

Как наречие в значении "*очень много*":
*В яблоке полно свежего сока.*

Глагол "п**о**лнить" существует, но он устаревший:
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/полнить](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

Викисловарь выдаёт такие причастия:
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/полнимый](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9)
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/полненный](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)
Соответственно, яблоко полнимо или полненно.
Но такие формы не употребляются, так как сам глагол устаревший. Вместо них употребляется причастие "наполнено":
*Блюдо наполнено (чем?) свежим соком.

Ведро наполнено (чем?) молоком.*

Comment: Тама, где твой коммент, уже поздно реагировать - место захвачено. (Согласен. Может, неназванное? – oleedd 7 часов назад). Вот смотрю - и думку думоваю: а что ж я такое имела в виду? чтоб так-то с согласованием лопухнуться, а? Спасибо, ща буду исправляться.